# Database data saved into string

Tags: java, android, json

Is it possible to retreive the data(TAG_NAME) from the database and save it as a string?

```
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    int success;
    try {

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phonenum", phonenum));

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                url_product_details, "GET", params);

        Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        if (success == 1) {

            JSONArray productObj = json
                    .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array

            JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);
```

I am only able to take the data a display it as a textview, but I want to save the data into a string.

```
            // product with this pid found

            txtwelcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtname);

            // display product data in EditText
            txtwelcome.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
```

I tried using this to save it into a string but it didn't work.

```
            username = product.getString(TAG_NAME);
```

Comment: What exactly didn't work when you tried `String username = product.getString(TAG_NAME);` ?

Comment: @IvanV the data did not get saved, as i tried to use the String username in a textview and nothing was shown.

Comment: Check will be shown in logs using `System.out.println(product.getString(TAG_NAME));`